# Error in IF statement powershell

Tags: powershell

I think there's a problem with this `if` statement.

```
Function Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled([string]$profile)
{
    Return [bool](Get-NetFirewallProfile -name "Domain" | Where Enabled -eq "False")
}


# If the firewall for some of the 3 profiles is not enabled
if ( ((Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Domain")) -or (Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Private")) -or (Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Public"))) -eq "False")
{
    Write-Output "Enabling..."
    # Enable Windows firewall for for all (the 3 profiles)
    Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Private,Public -Enabled True
}
```

Whether I have activated a firewall or not, this script always does nothing. What's happening?

---

**SOLUTION**

```
# Now this function is dynamic
Function Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled([string]$profile)
{
    Return [bool](Get-NetFirewallProfile -name $profile | Where Enabled -eq "True")
}


# If the firewall for some of the 3 profiles is not enabled
if ( -not(Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Domain")) -or -not(Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Private")) -or -not(Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Public")) )
{
    Write-Output "Enabling..."
    # Enable Windows firewall for for all (the 3 profiles)
    Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Private,Public -Enabled True
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robert mentioned, you are using the string `False`, not the Boolean `$false` in your `if` statement.

But the logic in your `if` statement isn't working as expected:

```
if(((Boolean) -or (Boolean) -or (Boolean)) -eq $false)
```

will not produce the desired result in Powershell (it will only execute if all of the values are `$false`). Since `if` always executes on  `$true`, you can achieve desired results by simply `-not`-ing the values from `Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled` like so:

```
if((-not(Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Domain")) -or (-not(Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Private")) -or (-not(Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Public")))
```

This will execute the `if` block when any of the values are `$false`.

Comment: Yes, this better IF statement didn't work before, so I programmed this worse IF, haha, thx.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `$false` not `"False"`.

"False" is a string literal and will never match if the boolean value returned by the condition `((Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Domain")) -or (Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Private")) -or (Get-IsFirewallProfileEnabled("Public")))` is false.

For example:

`if ("False") { write-host "true" }`

The line above will always write "true" to the host. This is because a non-empty string literal equates to $true.

The line below will never write "true" to the host.

`if ($false) { write-host "yes" }`